# How to call a js function that is included into $(function()?

Tags: javascript

```
$(function() {
  function say() {
  alert("hello");
}
});
```

Is there a way to call say() from the console ?

Comment: That depends on what `$` is and what it does with the argument it gets. If it only gets executed once, I bet you can't access `say()` because it only exists in local scope.

Comment: Saving in the global context

Comment: @ThomWiggers There is nothing the `$` function could do to expose  `say` function in the given code. It might use the source of the anonymous function to create another `say`  function e.g. in the global context, but that will be a different function.

Comment: yarek, maybe write your use case, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it not make sense but...

```
$(function() {
    function say() {
        alert("hello");
    }
    window.say = say;
});
```

Comment: So I said does not make sense to expose that way. :)